# Using custom packaging type as dependency in maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have created a custom packaging type in my maven plugin so that I can deploy files in this custom format.

E.g. I have a project that uses this format for packaging.  The pom.xml has:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>mylib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>mybin</packaging>
....
```

I am able to deploy successfully to a repository.  But now I want to use this as a dependency in another project.

E.g. by adding something like this:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>mylib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>mybin</type>
        </dependency>
```

This is working fine, also except that `mybin` format includes some nested resources such as jar files) that I would like to include in the classpath.

I so far I've attempted to programmatically extract the jars from inside a mojo and programmatically add it to the project using `project.getModel().addDependency(systemJarDep)`, but this doesn't seem to be picked up by the compiler.

How can this be done in Maven?

Comment: Why do you handle jar files as resources? Why not let Maven resolve them transitively?

Comment: I have a custom file format which is basically a zip file with nested resources.  Some of these nested resources are jar files that I would like to include in the classpath.

Comment: If the jar's inside the zip that will not work...

Comment: So there is No API that I can implement in a plugin that will allow me to override how resources are resolved?  Is there any dependency type other than jar that supports being added to the classpath?

Comment: I still don't understand why you put the jars into the zip. Why not declare them in the POM and let Maven do the resolution?

Comment: The "zip" file includes sub-jars which are used for targeting different platforms.  It includes CSS files, native libs, native source files, some some jars with compiled classes, and other jars with sources which are compiled at runtime.

I want to be able to share the dependency as a single nice <dependency> snippet.  I don't want users to have to copy and paste three pages of XML into their project so that they can use this dependency.


So are you saying that maven can't resolve any dependencies to the classpath except jar files?

Comment: Nobody needs to copy/paste three pages of XML. Maven resolves transitive dependencies automatically. If your dependency has further dependencies, Maven downloads them without further configuration.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work.  My custom package type includes all of the required dependencies.  These dependencies are "built" at the time that my custom package is built.  So how do I tell maven about these dependencies?  I've included a dependency to my custom package artifact.

Is there a different type of packaging type I should be using to generate dependencies?

Comment: As J Fabian Meier already wrote you should use the default mechanism of Maven and do not try to prevent it...makes it harder to use ... So finally you have created your own packaging type to package different jar's into a single package. If this is the case this means you are reinvented the wheel. It sounds you should use the standard mechanisms. A jar is a defined format which contains classes. a zip file which has the same structure as a jar will also work (but can't be defined in Maven as a dependency) but a zip has a different structure is not supported by Maven neither by Java (JVM).

Comment: Furthermore what I've read about your type which contains source files (Java?) which are compiled at runtime sounds weird to me and resources like CSS files are usual resources can be packaged as a usual jar file which can put on the classpath in java can simply being loaded via getResources/getRecourceAsStream...

Comment: Another point native libs? What kind of native libs? Binding via JNI ? For which platforms? This would result being your whole build is platform dependent...

Comment: Lots of comments suggesting I should just use built-in mechanisms and not reinvent the wheel.  Would love to, but they are insufficient.  Many of the resources in this bundle (including CSS files) should not be on the classpath at all.  They just need to be accessible to the Maven plugin in order to build certain goals.  The CSS files, for example, should not be loadable via getResourceAsStream().

Comment: @khmarbaise The native files are files that will be used by the maven plugin to generate certain goals such as iOS apps, Android apps, native desktop apps, etc..  They are not JNI.  We have an established cross-platform toolchain, but have been using ANT.  Trying to switch to maven now.  Maven far less flexible - might not be able to handle it.  But trying.

Comment: That information would be helpful at the beginning cause iOS etc. I would have suggested not to try via Maven.. and yes Maven has it's limits for good reasons... maybe also a way to kotlin for Android etc. might be a better solution and...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you for taking the time to help.  "It can't be done" is still an answer that is helpful in forging a path forward.  This exchange has been helpful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this sort of thing cannot be done in Maven.

I am solving my problem by adjusting the format of my custom package type to be a jar file itself, with all of the classes that I want on the classpath directly inside it.  The other sub-resources that I don't require on the classpath (at least by default) are bundled inside the META-INF directory.

This is not ideal, but it is an acceptable solution for now.

Comment: Resources belong in the root of the JAR not in META-INF directory. Now what you are going to reinvent maven-shade-plugin (which has some disadvantages etc.)

Comment: @khmarbaise These resources should not be available on the classpath.  This is not reinventing the shade plugin.  These resources need to be available to our plugin only and used during certain goals.   If I put them in the root of the jar, then I'd have to do extra work in all goals to filter them out.

Comment: So you are already violating the JAR standards... META-INF directory is not intended for resources. So I see.. it's up to you...

Comment: @khmarbaise The original "legacy" file format didn't violate any JAR standards because it wasn't a jar.  Maven's limitations in this area have forced me to reformat it as a jar, since that is the only thing that maven understands.  In doing so, I have no choice but to "violate" the standards.

Comment: A little bit more research, and found that including resources in META-INF doesn't violate  JAR standards at all.  In fact, this where multi-release jars place their version-specific .class files.  https://nipafx.dev/multi-release-jars-multiple-java-versions/